# Custom header on IOS stays visible when it's not supposed to

Tags: ios, react-native, header

**Current Behavior**
When I move from a screen with Header to a screen without header, The header stays visible and doesn't hide. It's a custom header. The thing is it's not even a header. It seems like an image that doesn't respond any touch. You can press other touchables under it.

What code are you running and what is happening?

```
<AppStack.Navigator> 
 <AppStack.Screen name="Tabs" 
 component={TabScreens} 
 options={({ route, navigation }) => ({ 
 header: () => <CommonHeader title={getHeaderTitle(route)} 
 leftButton={HeaderLeftButtonEnum.empty} navigation={navigation} /> 
})}/> 
<AppStack.Screen name="QRScreen" component={QRScreen}/> 
</AppStack.Navigator>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6BKp.jpg)

```
<LinearGradient colors={["#900000", "#D00"]} start={[0, 0]} end={[0.65, 0]} >
```